# How to render html partial in vue 3 router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my apps I have a couple of pages that show some embedded forms...

The forms come from jotform, and are embedded with a js script like this

```
<section>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://form.jotform.com/jsform/123124124"</script>
</section>
```

I cannot find a way to load this inside a component, so I'm trying to use a simple HTML partial. Is there a way to do this?

I try also with a component but it doesn't work

```
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({

    }),
    mounted() {
      const scripts = [
          "https://form.jotform.com/jsform/123124124124"
        ];
      scripts.forEach(script => {
              let tag = document.head.querySelector(`[src="${ script }"`);
              if (!tag) {
                  tag = document.createElement("script");
                  tag.setAttribute("src", script);
                  tag.setAttribute("type", 'text/javascript');
                  console.log(document.body);
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    document.body.appendChild(tag);
                  }, 500)

              }
          });
    }
  }
</script>



<template>
  <main class="main">
    <h1 class="visuallyhidden">Funding Request</h1>
    <section class="funding">

    </section>
  </main>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://www.jotform.com/answers/2829655-how-to-use-jot-form-with-react) you can try to use the iFrame version: https://www.jotform.com/help/148-getting-the-form-iframe-code/

FYI: including an embed script within a dynamic vue component is not an easy thing (as the JotForm support explaned [here](https://www.jotform.com/answers/1893186-how-to-embed-a-form-in-a-vuejs-page)), so you might try to go for the iFrame version if it works for you :)

Comment: The iframe embed of jotform is compesed by an iframe + a script :-/

Comment: You can try to add that iFrame in a component and that script in the `created()` method of the same component (I think the script needs to be adapted).